# how to get the number of partitions in a dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I know there are many questions on the same but none really answers my question.

**I have scenario data.**

```
   val data_codes = Seq("con_dist_1","con_dist_2","con_dist_3","con_dist_4","con_dist_5")
    val codes = data_codes.toDF("item_code")
    val partitioned_codes = codes.repartition($"item_code")
    println( "getNumPartitions : " + partitioned_codes.rdd.getNumPartitions);
```

**Output :**

```
getNumPartitions : 200
```

it suppose to give 5 right why it is giving 200 ? where am i doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 200 is the standard value of `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` which is applied to `df.repartition`. From the docs :

> Returns a new Dataset partitioned by the given partitioning
>   expressions, using spark.sql.shuffle.partitions as number of
>   partitions. The resulting Dataset is hash partitioned.

The number of partitions is **NOT RELATED** to the number of (distinct) values in your dataframe. Repartitioning ensures that all records with the same key are in the same partition, nothing else. So in your case it could be that all records are in 1 partition and 199 partitions are empty

Even if you do `codes.repartition($"item_code",5)`, there is no guarantee that you have 5 equally sized partitions. AFAIK you cannot to this in dataframe API, maybe in RDD with custom partitioner

Comment: @BdEngineer as I said, you could do `codes.repartition($"item_code",data_codes .size)`, but still this will not give you 1 row per partition. A partition is just a chunk of data, you should not worry too much about the exact size of paritions or whether you have some empty partitions...

Comment: @BdEngineer in `mapPartitions`, you need an additional `groupBy` on the `Iterator[Row]` to separate the codes. To do this, you need to convert the `Iterator` to something like  `List` or `Vector`

Comment: @BdEngineer I would suggest to ask a different question on this